# Is it possible to use ReportViewer with ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, reportviewer

I'm trying to use ReportViewer (it must be ReportViewer!) with Asp.NET MVC. Is it possible?

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a webform for that or use the [SOAP functionality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155395(SQL.90).aspx)

Comment: problem is only with MVC webforms mishmash

Answer (score 1):

Report Viewer requires view state, and you do not have that in ASP.Net MVC.

There are two ways to do this.

- Have one page on you site that is a normal web page and use that to display the report viewer.
- Let your asp.net MVC page call your report server and then stream out the Http response to the client (we use this for PDF reports)

Answer (score 0):

Any control that does not use ViewState or require `runat=server` can be used in ASP.NET MVC without problems.

The construction of ASP.NET MVC allows report writing in a view to be a relatively straightforward proposition.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367332/would-the-msft-report-viewer-rdlc-work-with-mvc

Answer (score 0):

You will want to put the report viewer on a Web Form.  Check out the second section on this page.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/mixing-asp.net-webforms-and-asp.net-mvc