# How do I navigate to a Web Forms ASPX page from my MVC3 application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, reportviewer

I find myself having to create a Web Form page in my MVC3 application to host the ReportView control, for displaying rdlc reports for my users. I see quite an abundance of advice on how to go about this all, and it seems pretty simple.

What I would like to know is how do I get from a Razor based view to this report viewer page? Do I simply 'hard-code' a content url to the page, or is there some more polite way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `Url.Content` helper:

```
<a href="@Url.Content("~/report.aspx")">Show me the report</a>
```

Comment: Thanks @Darin, that is what I meant with my 'hard-coded' url, hard in that it is an actual url, not an action. I'm starting to feel a bit more comfortable using the content helper inside an iframe, inside a regular controller managed view though.

Comment: Well that's exactly what classic WenForms are: `actual urls` and not `actions`. So yo uhave to reference them as such.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by adding route in global.asax file.

```
     routes.MapRoute(
         "ReportRoute",                         // Route name
         "Reports/{reportname}",                // URL
         "~/Reports/{reportname}.aspx"   // File
      );
```

Check out [LeftyX solution with source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5296485/bind-report-to-reportviewer-in-web-mvc2).